# how to call method from another window in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have two windows `win1` for display a list of Users and the other `win2` for adding user.

I  also have a method to refresh the grid after deleted or updated or added user. This method is in `win1`.

How  do I call this method from `win2` after add user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty basic Object Oriented Design question. So you want to be able to call back from `win2` to a function in `win1` after a user is added on `win2`. Well, does `win2` have a reference to the `win1` object? If so, then that's how you call it. If not, then you need to give it one (passing it in to the constructor or something).

Alternatively, if you're using an MVVM framework, you could go down the route of using a Messenger. Most of the MVVM frameworks have one included and they're very useful. I recommend going that route unless this is some sort of throwaway program where the plumbing wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

- You could use a custom event in your child window that the parent
  window listens to
- You could define a delegate in the child window
  that references a method in the parent window
- You could use a messenger of some form: Here is a sample:
  http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening Window 2 from Window 1, you could do something like:

```
// code in Window1
public void AddNewUser()
{
    Window2 window = new Window2();
    if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // Update DataGrid
        RefreshDataGrid();
    }
}
```