# wpf events between two windows

Tags: c#, wpf

Can someone please illustrate for me how to set up a logic like this:

I have a WPF Control. When a button is pressed it does one of the two possible things.

A. It checks if a different WPF Window has been loaded. If it was, it triggers that window's Print method. 
B. It checks if a different WPF Window has been loaded. If it was not, it instantiates that window and then triggers its Print method.

I struggle to understand the events system between two WPF Controls/Windows. It's a relatively new thing for me, so I would appreciate if someone walked me through this.

Ps. This is not a homework assignment, but rather a new hobby of mine. If its a totally noob question then just point me to a resource so I can educate myself.

Cheers!

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to provide a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates your scenario. I will point out that you seem to be viewing the problem wrongly. That is, the print command should belong to a view model that knows how to print, and you shouldn't have to navigate the event system to invoke a command on the view model for it to print. The UI and event routing in WPF are there for the user to interact with the view, which in turn interacts with the view models. The view itself shouldn't be implementing features except those directly related to the user's interaction.

Comment: How about using Observer - Subscriber Design Pattern for your case.I think it will be a good solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what is the way by which you will check if new `Window` opened is what you need it to be ?

You might do this by comparing their `Handle` or their `Type` (*public class MyWindowWithPrintMethod : Window*).

There can be multiple ways of doing this.

I suggest my simple way, focusing on the WPF way, to solve your purpose in easiest way possible.

```
    MyWindowWithPrintMethod obj_MyWindowWithPrintMethod;
    private void btnNewWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       obj_MyWindowWithPrintMethod = new MyWindowWithPrintMethod();
       obj_MyWindowWithPrintMethod.Show();
    }

    private void btnCheckNewWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       WindowInteropHelper tgtWindow = new WindowInteropHelper(obj_MyWindowWithPrintMethod);

       foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
       { 
          // Compare Handle
          WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(w);
          if (wih.Handle == tgtWindow.Handle)
          { 
            ((MyWindowWithPrintMethod)w).Print();
          }

          // Compare Type
          if (w.GetType() == typeof(MyWindowWithPrintMethod))
          {
            ((MyWindowWithPrintMethod)w).Print();
          }
       }
    }
```

**MyWindowWithPrintMethod.cs**

```
     public class MyWindowWithPrintMethod : Window
     {
         public void Print()
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Print invoked !");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901042/643828) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901007/sending-event-between-2-wpf-windows) about events from 2 windows may help:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Child childWindow = new Child();
        childWindow.MyEvent += new EventHandler(childWindow_MyEvent);

        childWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    void childWindow_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // handle event
        MessageBox.Show("Handle");
    }
}
```

**Child window**

```
public partial class Child : Window
{
    // define event
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    protected void OnMyEvent()
    {
        if (this.MyEvent != null)
            this.MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public Child()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Child_Loaded);
    }

    void Child_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // call event
        this.OnMyEvent();
    }
}
```

The above code shows how to set up an event from one window to another. But, you might want to simply call a method in that other window instead. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728209/how-to-call-method-from-another-window-in-wpf):

```
public void AddNewUser()
{
    Window2 window = new Window2();
    if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // Update DataGrid
        RefreshDataGrid();
    }
}
```

If you are determined to stick with events, then you should read up on [WPF routed events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How about using Observer - Subscriber Design Pattern for your case.I think it will be a good solution for this